# Triangles in the Gauss Plane

Tags: geometry

What is the image of $z$ ($z=a+ib$) in $C$ ($z$ is complex number) under reflection in the line which passes through $O$ at angle $\theta$ to the real axis?
Since one rotation can be factored into a product of two reflections, which means the question contains 3 reflections? Anyone has hint? What should I do?

Comment: No, no, just a single reflection. However, you may wish to compute it by rotating $-\theta$, reflecting in the real axis (this is easy: $f(z)=\bar z$), and then rotating $\theta$.

Comment: and which is (ze^(iθ))z'(ze^(i(-θ)))?

Comment: Write out the three steps clearly, then compose functions.

Comment: rotating −θ:ze^(-iθ);  reflecting in the real axis: z';  rotating θ: ze^(iθ), then function is ze^(iθ)z'ze^(-iθ) ?

Comment: Compose functions, not multiply!

Comment: I know, (ze^(iθ))(z')(ze^(-iθ))

Comment: No. If $f(z)=z^2$ and $g(z)=z+1$, what is $(f\circ g)(z)$?

Comment: (z+1)^2, how can I compose rotating −θ and reflecting in the real axis?

Comment: $f(z)=\bar z$, $g(z)=e^{i\theta}z$. $(f\circ g)(z)=$?

Comment: I got it..thanks, great help!!

Answer (score -1):

The slope of the specified line is $\tan\theta$ or $\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$. The slope of any normal to the specified line is the negative reciprocal of that (or $- \frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$). Plug $a$, $b$ and that value into the point-slope equation of a line. Solve that equation and the equation of the original line $\left(\sin\theta\right)x=\left(\cos\theta\right)y$ simultaneously to find the intersection of the two (say, $(c|d)$. The coördinates of the desired reflection point are $(2c-a|2d-b)$ or: $- a + 2 a \cos^2 θ + 2 b \cos θ \sin θ + (- b + 2 a \cos θ \sinθ + 2 b \sin^2 θ) i$.

Comment: It would be more helpful, if you added an explanation to what your answer means.

Comment: I think it's better to keep z, instead of using z=a+bi

Comment: @Harish Chandra Rajput  It is answered ok  already more than a year before,  why edit now?